# Create and show custom events on particular day in Calendar view in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I have a requirement of showing some custom events or tasks on a particular day of the month. It shows some tasks or events to the user.

I have attached a sample image where it has some events or tasks with colour codes like red, green and some amount in black.

Let me know how can I achieve this. I'm open to use any third party tools or API's.

[image: This is the tasks or events sample in android calendar view]

Thanks & Regards

Amit Jangid

Comment: You can try https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: I tried this and I think it's not supported in this library. If possible can you provide a sample code where my requirement is met??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library in github com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.7.0 https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View